# Upload Image Application is working fine on emulator but unable to upload Image on test phone

Tags: android

**Upload Image Application: It is working fine on emulator but unable to upload Image on test phone. It chooses pic from gallery but doesnt display anything in Imageview.**

```
 public class Uploadimage extends Activity {
        public static int requestCode=1;
        Button b1;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_uploadimage);     

         b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, requestCode);         
            }
        });
        }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
      {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data) ;
        if (requestCode==1 && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
            Uri image = data.getData();
            String [] filepath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(image, filepath, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(filepath[0]);
            String path= cursor.getString(column);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imageview= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));           
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you get any error? Have you add permission to manifest file?

Comment: You need to convert your image to bitmap before the set of image

Comment: if you just care about setting the image to imageView then set the imageView by Uri like this imageView.setImageUri(image);

Comment: no.. i dint get any error.

Comment: have you add permission of write and read external storage?

Comment: @Androidgeek: Have to develop more application so need to convert to bitmap. uri(image) wont be good option. Moreover, it is not going to solve phone issue.

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes. i did. thats why able to access to gallery. but after selecting pic, it is not getting displayed on imageview.

Comment: on which device are you testing ?? -@apurva

Comment: @AndroidGeek Samsung Galaxy s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following method for decoding your file path.

```
public void decodeFile(String filePath) {

// Decode image size
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

// The new size we want to scale to
final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

// Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;

int scale = 4;
while (true) {
    if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
        break;
    width_tmp /= 2;
    height_tmp /= 2;
    scale *= 2;
}

BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o2.inSampleSize = scale;
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2); // this bmp object of Bitmap is global and you can set it to your ImageView.
}
```

Now you can call this function after this one

```
 String path= cursor.getString(column);
 decodeFile(path);
```

Comment: @dipali And what about you??

Comment: @PiyushGupta heiyyee It worked... Thanks. But May i know why my earlier code was working on emulator but not on device?

Comment: In Device the image may be in MB. In some way we can say that there is also captured images from camera so it will be in MB. So basically it can't be decoded simply. for that we have to use this one.

Answer (score 0):

If your get the content from the  mobile, below code must write in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

use this below code you will get the solutions..

```
   `buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){ 
  @Override
   public void onClick(View v) 
   {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
      android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
      startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

    }});
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
         Uri targetUri = data.getData();
         Bitmap bitmap;
         try 
         {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));

            targetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
          } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
          {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }`
```

Comment: already done this.. thats why it is working fine on emulator. i dnt knw why unable to load pic on phone